# Load big text file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, flat-file

I want to load a very big file 3GB of text ( not comma separated ) just a text so each line in the text become a record

my table structure should be like this

LoadedTable
ID bigint identity
TLine varchar(max)

I tried using SQL tasks to import data but always get this error

> - Executing (Error) Messages Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 0" returned
>     status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more
>     characters had no match in the target code page.".  (SQL Server Import
>     and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source -
>   NOTEEVENTS_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Column 0]"
>   failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition
>   on "Source - NOTEEVENTS_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source
>   Output].Columns[Column 0]" specifies failure on truncation. A
>   truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing
>   file "E:\MyFile.txt" on
>   data row 1.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source -
>   NOTEEVENTS_csv returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned
>   a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The
>   meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error
>   is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure. 
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

How to fix this error and load each line as a record with ID shows the line order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max storage size for a `VARCHAR(max)` column (row) is 2Gb, [as per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments):

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ] Variable-size string data. Use n to define the
>   string size in bytes and can be a value from 1 through 8,000 or use
>   max to indicate a column constraint size **up to a maximum storage of**
>   **2^31-1 bytes (2 GB)**.

---

(*For demo purposes I've used the [big.txt file from Peter Norvig's site](https://norvig.com/big.txt)*)

Instead of using the user interface in SSMS, you can run a BULK INSERT query, like the one below:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ROW_NR
    , *
INTO MyTable
FROM OPENROWSET
    (BULK N'C:\..\Desktop\big.txt', FORMATFILE=N'C:\..\Desktop\big_format_file.xml') tmp
```

However, you need to do a few things before:

1. Create a [Format File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), in order to specify the format (like you would specify a row terminator, column terminator for a Flat File import). (*an easy workaround to generating this file at the bottom of my answer*)

   I chose to create a .XML file format because it's easier to read. The content of this file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="txt" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Although this is a sample document, make sure that the **TERMINATOR** option has set the correct terminator that you expect to have as a row delimiter.

2. After that, you can run the query above to import your data into `MyTable`.

   From this point on, you can either use SELECT INTO to persist the information into a new table, INSERT to add new rows to an existing table or even UPDATE to update columns into an existing table.

In my case, the contents of `MyTable` will look like:

[image]

---

**An easy workaround to creating the Format File** is to create a table in the database, with the structure you're expecting the input data to have is to:

1. Create dummy table with the structure / definition (ex: big_bulk)

> create table big_bulk (txt varchar(max))

2. Run BCP command to generate the File Format out of this table:

> **bcp test.dbo.big_bulk format nul -c -x -f .\Desktop\big_format_file.xml -t, -T**
>
> The **-t** parameter in the bcp command above specifies the row delimiter. You can replace the comma ( "," ) with a "\t" or "\r" or other [Field and Row Terminators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

3. Edit the XML file and make sure you set the correct row terminator/delimiter.
4. Use the File Format in your `OPENROWSET()` query.